# how can stop repeat $.ajax response codes?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post, submit

I created some form for get data from user and insert data to database , i wanna use $.ajax for append elemnts to body tag and also use $.ajax for submit form to database but there is a problem that when user click to submit info it will insert user info it will insert data to database several time

for example

```
function admin_addcity() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "elemnts.php",
        data: {
            vals: "form_elemnts"
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $('body').empty();
            $('body').html(response)
            form_events();
        }
    });
}

function form_events() {
    $('#form_submit_button').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insertformdata.php",
            data: {
                firstname: $("#firstname").val(),
                lastname: $("#lastname").val()
            },
            success: function (response) {
                // this ajax insert data to database several time 
                alert("data is inserted to database");
            }
        })
    }
```

User click on submit button just one time but it will repeat ajax serveral time, how can fix that?

Comment: Disable the button when submitting using ajax

Comment: no user just click one time and it will insert data to database several time, i don't know for why

Comment: You're calling `form_events` function multiple times, so binding `click` event again and again. It should be called only once. Remove the function `form_events` and wrap the click handler in `ready`

Comment: how can do that?it don't will work if click event added to ready handler because the elemnts is not in body at first and it will append to body tag

Comment: Check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ev6htpgm/)

Comment: you can use:`$('#form_submit_button').on("click",function () {//}); ` in your document ready part then no need of calling `form_events`.

Comment: Thank you Suchit and Tushar but it don't work for me i doing append elements from database and form_submit_button is not a html tag at first and it will append from database with $.ajax so it can work with ready handeler